# How to instruct GPT Davinci 003 not to prefix with a sentence like "The JSON array would look like this:"?

Tags: openai-api

Often when I try to generate code with OpenAI's text-davinci-003 model, the output is lead by a introductory sentence.

In an instance where I instructed the code to list all the variables in a PHP file using JSON, the returned result starts with:

```
The JSON array would look like this:
```

...followed by indeed a JSON array with the desired result — so that's great. However, the introductory line makes it hard for me to parse the JSON.

**Question:** Is there a way to instruct text-davinci-003 not to include a introductory sentence and "get right to it"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two ways:

1. Prompt design.
2. One-shot training.

*Prompt Design*

This was a prompt I tested in the OpenAI playground.

```
The following is PHP code. Return only a JSON response with a list of all the variables and their values. The variables will be the key and the values the JSON values.

[Code]
<?php

$name = "John";
$age = 25;
$location = "New York";

echo "My name is $name, I am $age years old and I live in $location.";

?>

[JSON]
```

GPT returned the following response:

```
{"name": "John", "age": 25, "location": "New York"}
```

*One-shot training*

This is where you provide a single example in the prompt with example code and an example output. This primes GPT to provide the answer in the format you like.

```
The following is PHP code. Return only a JSON response with a list of all the variables and their values. The variables will be the key and the values the JSON values.

[Example Code]
<?php

$name = "John";
$age = 25;
$location = "New York";

echo "My name is $name, I am $age years old and I live in $location.";

?>

[Example JSON]
{"name": "John", "age": 25, "location": "New York"}

[Code]
<?php

$name = "John";
$age = 30;

echo "My name is $name and I am $age years old.";

?>

[JSON]
```

Make sure to use the OpenAI playground to test your prompts and get the response you want before adding it to your code.

https://platform.openai.com/playground

Comment: Thank you for the insights, Kane! I will use them.